# Make envelope icon disappear in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, notification-area

I have my mobile phone synced with my Exchange server.  When an email comes and I'm on the road, I read it and it is marked as read.  When I get back to my computer, the envelope icon displays in the task bar, even though I have no new unread messages.  If I right click the envelope, I can choose the option "hide this envelope", but then it doesn't show up even if I get new mail.  The only way I can make the envelope go away is to close Outlook.

Anyone know how to tell the envelope "thank you, but i've already read all the email, go away until there is more new mail"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keyboard hotkey in the main Outlook window.

Its primary function is to mark the selected messages as read. As a side-effect, it will also remove the envelope icon.

Comment: This is better than opening the email and closing it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I've found so far is kinda kludgy.  Open a read message in outlook and this seems to force outlook to refresh the status indicator and hide the envelope until new mail arrives.

Comment: That's better than closing outlook and reopening it...