# Outlook 2007 showing new mail icon with false positives

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

For the last few days, Outlook 2007 has been displaying the new mail icon every once in a while throughout the day when I actually did not have any new mail. To get rid of this icon, as soon as I double click any email that I had already read, the icon goes away.

Has anyone else seen something like this before?

Comment: Is the "envelope" is set to be "always displayed" in the task bar?

Comment: nope, it is not.

Comment: Do you have a rule that move/delete incoming email so that you don't see anything new in the inbox but in fact, you got a new mail??

Comment: nope. i do have rules for moving mails with a specific subject into specific folders though... however lately i have checked this folders at the moment the icon appears, and in fact no new mail had arrived...

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/4324/make-envelope-icon-disappear-in-outlook-2007 But now, I'm kinda clueless for your issue. I would try to simply reinstall Outlook.

Comment: I have the exact same issue in Outlook 2013.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're getting a new mail notification for emails that show up in your "Junk e-mail" folder. I have the same issue using the exchange protocol to access my hotmail account. I haven't yet found a solution, but the first step to finding one is to first identify the problem. There may be a way to build a rule to fix this.